# Run Username SQL Query from WordPress Child Theme Functions File

Tags: mysql, user-meta

Having an admin account, I can change everything except the username (which happens to be the login name). I am therefore wondering how to change the username using the functions file.

Running the below as a SQL query works fine, but how do I "convert" it into a function?

```
add_action('init','username_query');
function username_query() {
    
    global $wpdb;
    $result = (UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_login`= 'new-admin-name-here' WHERE `user_login`='old-admin-name-here');

}
```

Any help is appreciated and yes; I know that the user will be logged out and asked to login again.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can achieve this... In your instance, as you pointed out $wpdb, here is the possible ways you can achieve this:

#### 1. Use $wpdb::query

You can run this query directly using $wpdb's query method as:

```
add_action("init", "username_query")
function username_query(){
    global $wpdb;

    $prefix  = $wpdb->prefix;

    $query   = "UPDATE `{$prefix}wp_users` SET `user_login`= 'new-admin-name-here' WHERE `user_login`='old-admin-name-here'";

    $results = $wpdb->query( $query );

    if( $results === false ){
        return "Error updating admin";
    }

    return "Admin username updated";
}
```

#### 2. Use $wpdb::update

You can also use $wpdb's update method to run your query as in below example

```
add_action("init", "username_query")
function username_query(){
    global $wpdb;

    $updated_rows = $wpdb->update(
                                  "wp_users", 
                                  array( "user_login" => "new_admin_name_here" ), 
                                  array( "user_login" => "old_admin_name_here" ),
                                  array( "%s" ),
                                  array( "%s")
                                );

   if ( $updated_rows === false ){
        return "Error updating admin";
   }

   return "Admin username updated";

}
```

Comment: some minor mistakes in the code that I were able to fix myself. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.